Как отправить сообщение боту (Wtelegramclient)?
Я хочу отправить сообщение боту с помощью библиотеки Wtelegramclient. Когда получаю все чаты, боты не отображаются как InputPeer или MessageBase.
var chats = await client.Messages_GetAllChats();

